# Saving a Video into gallery using path_provider package

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-dependencies

I have been Working on a small project where users can download WhatsApp status directly into their gallery. I made two tabs. one tab for WhatsApp Images and another for Videos. I could successfully download images into the gallery. now, I am facing a problem while downloading a Video into the gallery. I used path provider to download the video into the gallery. the Video gets downloaded in `storage\emulated\0\android\data\com.JeevanCrasta.stikkers\files\videos\`

I want to download those videos in the `storage\emulated\0\Stikkr\videos`directory. And those videos should be visible in the gallery. now those videos get downloaded in a different directory and are not visible in the gallary.

this is the code where videos get downloaded while the button is pressed :

```
floatingActionButton: FloatingActionButton(
        backgroundColor: Colors.teal,
        child: Icon(Icons.download_sharp),
        onPressed: () async {
          _onLoading(true, "");

          File originalVideoFile = File(widget.videoFile);
          Directory directory = await getExternalStorageDirectory();
          if (Directory("${directory.path.toString()}/Stikkr").existsSync()) {
            Directory("${directory.path.toString()}/Stikkr")
                .createSync(recursive: true);
          }
          String path = directory.path;
          String curDate = DateTime.now().toString();
          String newFileName = "$path/Stikkr/Videos/VIDEO-$curDate.mp4";
          // print(newFileName);
          await originalVideoFile.copy(newFileName);

          _onLoading(false,
              "If Video not available in gallary\n\nYou can find all videos at");
        },
      ),
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use package https://pub.dev/packages/gallery_saver 
1 Saves images and videos from network, it has to contain `http/https` prefix. 
2 Save temporary file to external storage 
Both images and videos will be visible in `Android Gallery` and `iOS Photos`.

In your case, file has downloaded, so you can pass `newFileName` and use

```
GallerySaver.saveVideo(newFileName).then((String path) {
          setState(() {
            secondButtonText = 'video saved!';
          });
        });
```

Comment: what is the path that he used in ios?